# What i7 MacBooks have?

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, benchmark, intel

Here I have a mid 2015 15" MacBook Pro, CPU is identified as:

```
  Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.2 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
```

How do I get the specific model of this CPU?

The [PassMark site](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html) presents a CPU benchmark and I would like to know how mine ranks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the Intel i7-4770HQ CPU, which is listed with a PassMarks score of 6,140.

In comparison, the current base model 16" MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon features the M1 Pro 10-core CPU, which is listed with a PassMarks score of 22,206.

Comment: Appreciate if you could add to the comparison:  
1. 2019 MacBook Pro 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9  
2. 2022 Macbook Air M2 10-Core GPU

Comment: The CPU in that 2019 MacBook Pro has a PassMarks score of 13,974. The CPU in the 2022 MacBook Air has a PassMarks score of 15,428. Note that the PassMarks score only says something about the CPU - not the GPU. So it doesn't matter for these scores how many GPU cores the M2 has.